# Expresión regular que haga match cuando no se repitan dígitos seguidos en un valor de 9 campos

Tags: javascript, regex

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de crear una expresión regular que haga match si cumple las siguientes condiciones:

1. -Debe contener 9 dígitos
2. -No debe inicar con 0
3. -No se debe repetir un digito seguido más de 3 veces, si se puede repetir a lo largo de todo el número pero seguidos no

Por ejemplo:

```
1000000000 false
100000000  false
111111111  false
122222222  false
201110111  True 
211111111  false
250000000  false
322222222  false
900900179  True
999999999  false
100000001  false
100000011  false
100001112  false
100002010  false
100009001  false
100099524  true
100110304  true
100111111  false
100222222  false
966366667  false
966666581  false
966666666  false
968777777  false
969999999  false
999595959  true
```

he intentando con esta expresion regular :

```
^[1-9]\d{8}$
```

No logro como validar que no se repita un número más de 3 veces.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es posible hacer una regex que cumpla esos criterios, pero quizá es posible hacer una que haga exactamente lo contrario, como `/^.{0,8}$|^.{10,}$|^0|([\d])\1{3}|[^\d]$/` para después poder negar el resultado de la evaluación.

```js
const arr = [1000000000,100000000,111111111,122222222,201110111,211111111,250000000,322222222,900900179,999999999,100000001,100000011,100001112,100002010,100009001,100099524,100110304,100111111,100222222,966366667,966666581,966666666,968777777,969999999,999595959,012345678,1234567890,12345,"12a2354566"];

const res = arr.filter(e=>!/^.{0,8}$|^.{10,}$|^0|([\d])\1{3}|[^\d]$/g.test(e));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, había llegado a esta solución alternativa: ^[1-9](?!.*(\d).*\1{4,})\d{8}$, probaré tu solución.

Comment: El 100009001 por ejempo, pasaría esa regex y no debería según los criterios.

Comment: Entiendo gracias por la aclaración, seguiré tu consejo. Gracias por tu respuesta @Emeeus